# Puppeteer infitine loop

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm very new with puppetter and trying to force it to do some actions in infinity loop. My idea is:

```
const initialisePuppeteer = async () => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false
})

const page = await browser.newPage()

await page.viewport({
  width: 1920,
  height: 1080
})
await page.goto(STUDIO_URL, { waitUntil: "load" })

//do actions

let element = await page.$('#center-panel')
let value = await page.evaluate(el => el.textContent, element)

//if (value.contains('special text')) - repeat all the operations
```

}

Can you help me to find out how i can achieve it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using simple do ... while for this case?

```js
const repeatIf = async <T>(
  action: (...args: any) => Promise<T>,
  condition: (...args: T[]) => Promise<boolean>,
) => {
  let result;
  do {
        result = await action();
  } while (await condition(result));
};
```

where action is

```js
    const action = async () => {
      await page.goto(STUDIO_URL, { waitUntil: "load" });

      return page.$('#center-panel');
    }
```

and condition is

```js
    const condition = (
      element: ElementHandle | null,
    ) => {
      return element
            ? page
                .evaluate((el) => el.textContent, element)
                .then((value) => value.contains('Your text'))
            : Promise.resolve(false);
    };
```

and then just call

```js
await repeatIf(action, condition);
```